# Understanding the theory, but not able to construct a multi-class project?

Tags: java

So this is my very first mini-javaproject and I have been stuck for days now on the basic structure and the (non existing) relation between anything within my code. I linked the code in my comment below, could not paste it in here for some reason - (Main is empty, so did not copy it.)

So I spent some time getting my head around the basics of Java (as my first programming adventure) and to be honest I felt pretty confident. (On Codewars I completed like 100+ Katas, but of course those are "single-class", so I was not prepared for the "real world.)

It is hard to exactly pinpoint my question, but I will try to give some examples.

1, (Main is empty right now, but anyway) Basically "nothing can be used" in main. Like methods of objects, like room1, or player1, etc.

2, In my Room.java line 21-22 why is the object room1 not visible? Why does Intellij say "Unknown class: RoomArray if I just created that very thing before??

3, I understand that I am supposed to have my variables set to private, which I plan to do later on. Also, I should use setter and getter methods, which I tried to do so with basically everything. But for example in Player.java I have this

```
Player player1 = new Player(300, 50, "Conan", 75, false);

public Player getPlayer1() {
    return player1;
}
```

and if I try to use the getPlayer1() method in any other class it just simply can not see/access it?

3, And to make me even more confused Room1 class has access to getMyDungeon () method created in the Dungeon class. Why is that so?

(Maybe it has to do with inheritance? The fact that Room1 extends Room which extends Room? But if so, it seems strange because not all classes can have a HAS-A or IS-A relationship with something. An example - if I create all 10 Rooms later on as Room1, Room2, etc. in separate classes, how could I ever create a Room [] array containing them? No matter where I started to do that it will always give me the error "Cannot resolve smybol" for all the Room objects...)

I have spent the past few days reading up on the topic and understand it all, but still when I try to build this project it all falls apart. I realize that an experienced programmer might not even my question because how basic it is, but if anyone can help me to get this whole thing clear in my head, I would appreciate it. (Really not looking for the complete code, but just some direction I should go, or the missing step, etc.)

Comment: The code itself (I could not include the links somehow) https://gist.github.com/neszkvik89/942c1c116b567ac5f5834efae93fc56c
https://gist.github.com/neszkvik89/3abeefcd5e3e18197fc1b2362e6f4643
https://gist.github.com/neszkvik89/e0fd8580bbdb69cd6d2dc00e9485d350
https://gist.github.com/neszkvik89/bb0b9f51881767a9fb980efbdd3c3e43
https://gist.github.com/neszkvik89/76495bd976bc760ca098d6b92cec6fdb

Comment: There's too much here.  Please narrow the question to one specific problem/error and demonstrate that problem with code in the question.

Comment: you not supposed to create  Player player1 = new Player(300, 50, "Conan", 75, false); inside your  Player class, move this code to other class(where you need it)...

Comment: What you typically want to do is create instances of classes not in the classes themselves, but in a separate class that only contains a main function (this class is known as a Runner). Eventually, when you start making windows, the main function of the class extending the windowing frame (java.awt.Frame is what I recommend, as opposed to javax.swing.JFrame) will serve as the runner.

Comment: "you not supposed to create Player player1 = new Player(300, 50, "Conan", 75, false); inside your Player class, move this code to other class(where you need it)... " This makes sense to me, but what if I need that Player1 object in lets say 8 different classes? I should use a getPlayer1 () method for it, right? Problem is I tried to to this, but it did not seem to work. :(

Comment: there are some ways to do so, the simplest you can use Singleton design pattern, I recommend to do so on the game object and bring the player from it, In general, Do not create many Singletons, create one and Inside it create other instances you need(Of course logically)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you to be trying to create an object within the class of that object The correct use is:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   Player player1 = new Player(300, 50, "Conan", 75, false);
}
```

or if you want your Room class to have a lot of players

```
public class Room {
  //this object will be create when you do Room room = new Room();
  List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
  public void createPlayer(){
    players.add(new Player());
  }
  //this is a getter 
  public List<Player> getPlayers() {
      return players;
  }
}
```

your Player:

```
public class Player {
  //Fields and Methods
}
```

and your main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Room room =new Room();
    room.createPlayer();
    for (Player p:room.getPlayers()) {
        //p.doSomething
    }
}
```

if you want an object to be created without the need to create an instance from the outside you need to use the static keyword (don't do that unless you know what you are doing)

```
static Player player1 = new Player(300, 50, "Conan", 75, false);

public static Player getPlayer1() {
    return player1;
}
```